# Just testing a 2 pair twisted internet cable having 4 wires

Tags: ethernet, network, networking, cable

I am having a problem with my 2-pair ethernet cable. I have connected the 4th, 5th, 7th, and 8th pins, but the 4th pin is not working. I have checked the RJ45 connector and the cable with a multimeter, and everything seems to be fine. However, when I test the cable with a network cable tester, the 4th pin does not light up.

I have tried making several different cables, and I have the same problem with each one. However, when I make a 4-pair cable, it works fine.

I am not sure what the problem is. Could it be a problem with the cable itself? Or could it be a problem with the network cable tester?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you have 4 pairs, why not wire them all?  If I had to bet where the problem is between the cable tester and your wiring, my money is on you.

Comment: The UTP standard requires four pairs (8 wires). The standard has pairs 1-2, 3-6, 4-5, and 7-8. See [this answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/55573/8499).